# Bash - Copy some files with same extensions and different names to multiple folders called like the files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to do a script for linux that copy several files with same extension but different names into another directory with the same folders as files i want to copy and with the same name as the files, and these files, one by one, within their folder.

Example, i have this:

```
Directory X -
             abcd.zip
             cdab.zip
             adcb.zip
             ...
```

And with the copy i want to be like this:

```
Directory Y -
             abcd -
                   abcd.zip
             cdab -
                   cdba.zip
             adcb -
                   adcb.zip
             ...  -
                   ...
```

I don't know if i have explained well, sorry.

Thanks in advance.

SOLVED. I use this:

```
cd x

for file in *.zip; do
name="${file%.*}";
mkdir -p $name;
cp $file $name;
done
rm *.zip

cd ..

rsync x/* y
```

Comment: Have you tried yourself a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner:

```
for file in *.zip; do name="${file%.*}"; mkdir -p $name; cp $file $name/; done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. With this i solved the problem. Sorry i'm starting study Bash and my mind was KO. I didn't see that it wasn't very difficult. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
for file in *.zip
do
    destination=$(${filename%.*})##extract extension
    mkdir -p "${destination}" ## make directory if not present
    cp $file ${destination} ##copy the file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
directoryX=/pathtoX
directoryY=/pathtoY
for file in $directoryX/*; do
filename="${file##*/}"
dirname="${filename%%.*}"
cp "$file" "$directoryY"/"$dirname"/"$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner using `find`:

```
find X -name *.zip -exec sh -c "dir=Y/\$( basename {} .zip ) ; mkdir \${dir} && cp {} \${dir}/" \;
```

Before:

```
.
├── X
│   ├── abcd.zip
│   ├── adcb.zip
│   └── cdab.zip
└── Y
```

After:

```
.
├── X
│   ├── abcd.zip
│   ├── adcb.zip
│   └── cdab.zip
└── Y
    ├── abcd
    │   └── abcd.zip
    ├── adcb
    │   └── adcb.zip
    └── cdab
        └── cdab.zip
```

Note that this approach uses standard tools, but is not tuned for performance (it will invoke 4 processes for each result of find). This will only be a problem with a lot of files (it takes 4 ms for each extra file on my machine).

You need at least 2 extra processes (`mkdir` and `cp`) in any shell script solution though.